# Prove that if one is convergent almost surely then so is the other.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $(X_n), (Y_n)$ be two sequences of random variables that have the same distribution. Prove that if one is convergent almost surely then so is the other.

So we have that $P(X_1\leq t_1,...,X_n\leq t_n)=P(Y_1\leq t_1,...,Y_n\leq t_n)$ for all $n$ and for all real $t_1,...,t_n$. Then honestly I have no clue how to get the result. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that the event $\{X_n\ \text{converges}\}$ is measurable, i.e. is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the events $\{X_1 \le t_1, \ldots, X_n \le t_n\}$.  Note that a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy, i.e. 
$$\forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists N\;  \forall m,n > N, \ |X_m - X_n| < \epsilon $$
and it is enough to take $\epsilon$ of the form $1/k$.  Thus 
$$ \{X_n \ \text{converges}\} = \bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty \; \bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \;\bigcap_{m=N+1}^\infty\; \bigcap_{n=N+1}^\infty \{|X_m - X_n| < 1/k \}$$